# Kafka-python producer enable.idempotent

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, idempotent

i'm facing the duplication data in kafka so i want to use idempotent in kafka-python but unfortunately its not the part of it, how i can stop the duplication data in same partition with out idempotent or there is any way to import it or customize the current library?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use confluent_kafka, since kafka-python does not provide this feature. Have a look at this [link](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/apache-kafka-idempotent-producer-avoiding-message-duplication.html)

```
producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': ‘localhost:9092’,
          'enable.idempotence': True})
```

This feature was made available with the 1.0.0 release of librdkafka (a library written in C).